# How to connect to MySQL in C# using default credentials

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database with C# using default credentials. I am able to connect with the following code. The argument used here is the one suggested by MySQL.

```
    connectToMySQL(@"server=my_server;userid=my_id;password=my_password;database=my_database");

    public static MySqlConnection connectToMySql(string connectionInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            //instantiate the connection
            MySqlConnection mysqlConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionInfo);

            //open and close the mysql connection to make sure it works. it can be re-opened later
            mysqlConn.Open();
            mysqlConn.Close();

            //Return the connection
            return mysqlConn;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Print off error message and return a null connection
            //Throw exception, log error
            string n = Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText("\\logfile.txt", "Failed to connect to MySQL." + n + e.ToString() + n + n);
            throw new Exception ("Failed to connect to MySQL. ");
        }
    }
```

Now that I have that working, I want to create the argument using

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

to generate the password and username. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any way to get the default credentials into a string format. I realize that I could just prompt the user to enter their credentials, but that doesn't work with the application I'm programming. I am working in Visual Studios Express 2013 creating a Windows Form Application. I don't necessarily have to connect using System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials, so I am open to other solutions.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding that feature.  That's only for Kerberos or NTLM authentication.  You can never retrieve the user's password.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.6/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html